# Find matching words in a list and a string

Tags: python, string, performance, list, comparison

I am writing some code in Python and I want to check if a list of words is in a long string.  I know I could iterate through it multiple times and that may be the same thing but I wanted tp see if there is a faster way to do it.  What I am currently doing is this:

```
    all_text = 'some rather long string'
    if "motorcycle" in all_text or 'bike' in all_text or 'cycle' in all_text or 'dirtbike' in all_text:
        print 'found one of em'
```

but what I want to do is this:

```
keyword_list = ['motorcycle', 'bike', 'cycle', 'dirtbike']
if item in keyword_list in all_text:
            print 'found one of em'
```

Is there anyway to do this efficiently?  I realize I could do:

```
keyword_list = ['motorcycle', 'bike', 'cycle', 'dirtbike']
for item in keyword_list:
      if item in all_text:
            print 'found one of em'
```

But it seems like there would be a better way once the keyword list becomes long.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You still have to check them all at least until one is found to be in the text, but it can be more concise:

```
keyword_list = ['motorcycle', 'bike', 'cycle', 'dirtbike']

if any(word in all_text for word in keyword_list):
    print 'found one of em'
```

Comment: You could make `keyword_list` into a `set`

Comment: It would be more efficient to check the other way round: `any(word in keywords for word in text)`

Comment: text is not a list of words, you'll have to split it first.

Answer (score 6):

One way would be to build a [prefix tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) out of the keyword list.
Then you can iterate through the long string character per character.
At each iteration you try to find in the prefix tree the prefix in the big string starting at the current position. This operation takes `O(log k)` time, where the keyword list is of size k (assuming the prefix tree is balanced).
If the long string is of length n, then the overal complexity is just `O(n log k)`, which is much better then the naive `O(n k)` if k is large.

Answer (score 6):

How about this.

```
>>> keyword_list = ['motorcycle', 'bike', 'cycle', 'dirtbike', "long"]
>>> all_text = 'some rather long string'
>>> if set(keyword_list).intersection(all_text.split()):
...     print "Found One"
Found One
```

Comment: Good idea about using a `set`. However, no need to intersect the entire lot to find a truthy value... Use `any` and generator against a `keyword_list` set instead... Also, from your example, I would write it as `set(keyword_list).intersection(all_text.split())` - this avoids unnecessary conversion

Answer (score 5):

Using regular expression is probably the fast way.

```
re.findall(r'motorcycle|bike|cycle|dirtbike', text)
```

will return all matches of selected words.

Comment: This is a bad idea, as written. Because, for example, `|cycle|` will match bicycle, tricycle, unicycle, etc. Which is clearly not the original author's intent. You could improve this regex to use word boundary notations and such, but then you risk making it unreadable. The original author didn't specify how they definied "efficiently" (smallest amount of code? fastest run time? smallest memory use?), but regexes risk being very inefficient in CPU and RAM. Not *this particular* regex, but as a general class of solutions they need to be suggested with care.

Answer (score 2):

ya need to make all_text a variable or it wont work

```
keyword_list = ['motorcycle', 'bike', 'cycle', 'dirtbike']
all_text = input("what kind of bike do you like?")
for item in keyword_list:
      if item in all_text:
            print ('found one of em')
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer here really useful, it can be used to search substring also

https://www.askpython.com/python/list/find-string-in-list-python

```
ls = ['Hello from AskPython', 'Hello', 'Hello boy!', 'Hi']

matches = [match for match in ls if "Hello" in match]

print(matches)
```